# Invoke-AzVMRunCommand does not return the expected value when running Get-NetFirewallProfile

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

I am trying to use the `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand` on a VM in my Azure subscription.

My powershell looks like this

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -VMName $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $scriptPath
```

With the script in my `$scriptPath` looking like this

```
Get-NetFirewallProfile | ConvertTo-Csv
```

When running this however, the response seems to tell me that the windows firewall is enabled, even though I know for a fact it is not.

The `ConvertTo-Csv` is required for other parts of my script to function as needed, as `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand` returns a string object, which isn't too useful. Even without this however I still don't get the correct response

Does anybody know of any reason as to why this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the commands I was running check different areas of the registry from the GUI.

GUI:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\DomainProfile
```

CMDLETS:

```
HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\StandardProfile
```

This is where the issue came from.

If you have this issue, but sure to check both registry entries.

Answer (score 0):

> Invoke-AzVMRunCommand does not return the expected value when running Get-NetFirewallProfile

To check the status of the `firewall` status from remote computer with `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand`, you can use the below command in your script to show the details in a table format, instead of using `Get-NetFirewallProfile | ConvertTo-Csv`

```
Get-NetFirewallProfile | Select-Object Name, Enabled
```

Here is the result of above command.

[image]

If you want to check all the details of the `Windows firewall`, you can use the following command:

```
$firewall = Get-NetFirewallProfile
```

Alternatively, if you only need to check the **name** and the **firewall status**, you can use the command above.

**Script path**

```
$FilePath = "C:\Users\Venkat\Desktop\Firewall.csv"
$firewall = Get-NetFirewallProfile
$firewall | Export-Csv -Path $FilePath -NoTypeInformation
```

Here is a script that executes `scriptpath` on a remote machine.

```
Connect-AzAccount
Get-AzVM -name "venaktvm"
$scriptpath = "xxxxxxxxxx\Firewall.ps1" 
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName "VM-RG-Name" -Name "VM-NAME"  -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $scriptpath
```

**Result:**
[image]

Firewall details have been exported to **CSV**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this response however running this still returns saying that Domain, Private and Public firewalls are enabled even though they are not.

Comment: If the command **Get-NetFirewallProfile** shows an incorrect firewall status, please restart the VM and check again.

Comment: 1.Check the local [Group Policy settings](https://imgur.com/vhunI3l) on the machine.
2.Check the domain Group Policy settings for Windows Firewall, If the machine is part of an Active Directory domain.